# Prove that the normalizer of $K$ in $G$ is the largest group of $G$ containing $K$ as a normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $K$ be a subgroup of a group $G$

I've already proven that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $N_G(K)$

I need help proving that $N_G(K)$ is the largest subgroup of G containing $K$ as a normal subgroup

Thanks!

($N_G(K)$ is the normalizer of $K$ in $G$)

Comment: What is your definitions of normalizer? Is it $\{g\in G\mid gKg^{-1}=K\}$?

Comment: The tricky part here is showing that there *is* a largest such subgroup.  It's conceivable that there are two (or more) such maximal subgroups, neither of which is contained in the other.  The answer of @ArturoMagidin below shows you how to demonstrate that can't happen.

Comment: {$g \in G$ : $gK = Kg$}  i think they are equivalent

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation on the right by $g^{-1}$ to see that they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: To show $N_G(K)$ is the largest subgroup of $G$ in which $K$ is normal, show that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $K\triangleleft H$, then $H\subseteq N_G(K)$.

Comment: so now I have to prove that $hkh$^(-1) $\in K$ the only way this happens is if $hk=kh$ thus $H \subseteq N_G(K)$... is this a valid answer? can I assume the only way that happens is if $hk=kh$?

Comment: @catarina_apolskis: It is not true that $hk=kh$ must happen. But if $K\triangleleft H$, don’t you know that for all $h\in H$ you must have $hK=Kh$?

Comment: yes of course! so as it is a normal subgroup it is obviously in the normalizer! it makes sense, thank you!!!